# Durandal / Knockout - Creating viewModel from server data prior to bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Sorry as this questions is mainly `Knockout`, but is in `Durandal` so the viewModel and some bindings my not look familiar to `ko` anwser contributors.

Basically my view is comprised of a table that renders server data:

**view.html**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td data-bind="text: Company"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am on `ASP.net` so of course I use `signalR` to get my server data which represents each value in the table. This is an asynchronous call so it does not block the `Durandal` `Composition` callback which will do the Knockout bindings.

**viewModel.js**

```
define(['services/logger', 'global/session', 'jquery', 'knockout', 'knockout-mapping', 'hubs'],

function ($, ko, komapping) {
    ko.mapping = komapping; // Needed
    var myChildModel = function (Id) {
        this.activate = function () {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                con.server.getDetails(Id).done(function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
        };
    };
    return myChildModel;
});
```

I **REALLY** want to take the server return and map it into the viewModel itself as shown above as I can then  account for changes in the data on the server-side automatically (not included or relevant at this point), but as the viewModel does not exist prior to the [binding](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks) callback

Causing the expected error:

> Unable to process binding "text: function (){return Company }"
>   Message: Company is not defined; View: widgets/customerInfo; ModuleId:
>   widgets/customerInfo

To negate this issue I want to stop the Knockout `applyBindings`, then call it manually on my server return `.done` call back.

The Durandal docs do say you can stop the bindings, but does not include an example how or whether it is possible to have it apply the bindings manually when you want.

**[Durandal Docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks)**

Has anyone been able to deploy this technique before, maintaining the viewModel comes from the server, and is not created then hydrated after, or has deployed a similar technique with the same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a trivial problem to solve but why not just add a conditional if above it?

```
<table class="table" data-bind="if: isLoaded">
    <tr>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td data-bind="text: Company"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and just set isLoaded to false until your data is loaded async?

Comment: Wow sometime we take the simplest thing and just way over think them. That is EXACTLY what I should do and have done. Thanks so much [PW Kad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1200803/pw-kad), for the answer and your [contributions](http://pwkad.wordpress.com/category/javascript/durandal-js/) to the Durandal and Knockout communities. People like you keep people like me from going crazy and real help us further our knowledge.